# E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: rushi

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

When I try to run my application, it crashes again and again.
below is the method that I have created in DBHandler.java file

```
public Cursor CheckUsername() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE Username = "+ MainActivity.getValue() +" and password = "+MainActivity.getpassword()+";";
        return db.rawQuery(query,null);
    }
```

So to check whether username and password is correct I have also created `checklogin()` method in `MainActivity.java`
below is the code

```
 private void checkLogin() {
        final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.emaillogin);
        final EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.passwordlogin);

        //editText.setText("");
        password = editText1.getText().toString();
        //editText1.setText("");
        username = editText.getText().toString().trim();

        Cursor c = dbHandler.CheckUsername();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
        }


    }
```

**When I try to debug it shows**

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: rushi
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.software2.bloodbankmanagement, PID: 27590
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: rushi (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM register WHERE Username = rushi and password = 4567;
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1404)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1336)
        at com.example.software2.bloodbankmanagement.DBHandler.CheckUsername(DBHandler.java:176)
        at com.example.software2.bloodbankmanagement.MainActivity.checkLogin(MainActivity.java:94)
        at com.example.software2.bloodbankmanagement.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:31)
        at com.example.software2.bloodbankmanagement.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6412)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25341)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no such column error - sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969531/no-such-column-error-sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out with this query

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE Username = '"+ MainActivity.getValue() +"' and password = '"+MainActivity.getpassword()+"';";
```

note `'` character before and after every `String`. this should produce below query

```
SELECT * FROM register WHERE Username = 'value' and password = 'password';
```

btw. passing data with static reference kept in `Activity` (e.g. `MainActivity.getValue()`) is a VERY bad aproach, it leads you to future memory leaks. you should pass these credentials to `checkLogin` method. also handling database in main thread is very bad for performance, when your database grow then searching in it would be taking some time, during it you apps UI will be freezed. strongly consider threading, coroutines, just any async way for processing data

Comment: Yes. its working. but can you suggest me instead of taking passing data with static reference, Is there any other approach to pass the data?

Comment: well, pass it as argument to method... `public Cursor CheckUsername(String username, String password) { ...`

Comment: then inside use these passed arguments `String query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE Username = '"+ username +"' and password = '"+password+"';";`

Comment: in `Activity` (at least) remove `static` keyword from `username` and `password` declarations on top of the file and call `Cursor c = dbHandler.CheckUsername(username, password);` after fetching text from `EditText`s as you are doing this now

Comment: if you didn't know that passing arguments and modifying methods is possible then I STRONGLY, VERY STRONGLY recommend you to take some language course (Java as you picked or Kotlin, is modern way for Android), as lack in your knowlendge is HUGE and this will lead you to learn some very bad practises and in fact slows down your skills acquiring. good luck!

Comment: Now I'm in 3rd year. I have knowledge about core java. but I want to prepare for product based companies like amazon, google so it requires good knowledge of DSA. So for DSA , Should I learn C++? or should I continue with Java.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246476/discussion-between-rishi-ff-and-snachmsm).